# Specific association of two model contains same name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two  model `User` & `Speed`  . User has many speed

User contain `username, email, password, nameofwatch`

Speed contain `nameofwatch, speed, userid`

can associate between two model by  `nameofwatch`.

If nameofwatch in user = nameofwatch in speed

**appear current_user value of speed**

Comment: While defining model relationship, you can specify the foreign_key. Refer http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-foreign-key

Comment: can explain more ? Thanks @Santhosh

Comment: You should define the relationship like `belongs_to :user, foreign_key: "nameofwatch"`. For more details, refer the link

Comment: @Santhosh foreign_key alone won't cut it in this case, he will need to add primary_key as well, otherwise it will use it's id in `nameofwatch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set adequate [`primary_key`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-primary-key) and [`foreign-key`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-foreign-key). In your case, both will be `nameofwatch`, since you want to join with that column in both the tables.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # use primary key of user as nameofwatch, and foreign key as nameofwatch in speed
  has_many :speeds, foreign_key: 'nameofwatch', primary_key: 'nameofwatch'
end

class Speed < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: 'nameofwatch', primary_key: 'nameofwatch'
end
```

Comment: this enough or add migration ?

Comment: your problem statement doesn't give much details about what you already have or what you want to achieve. This answer just targets about how to setup the associations in that way.

Comment: yes Know this solution is well but necessary add add details like migration

Comment: want to join with that column in both the tables. you write this down this in model?

Comment: Not able to comprehend well, but yes, the associations go in models